# What programming language can I use to incorporate this into my website?

Tags: html

What programming language can I use to incorporate the transition between when the user clicks on the right arrow on the middle right hand corner of the screen in the [example](https://caferati.me). In addition, how can I place text next to the arrow?

Could someone recommend me any tutorials which I can also watch to develop my understanding of how to do this and get a basic starting template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of animation and transaction could be archived using both CSS and javascript. You can find easily a lot of useful resources and tutorials on the internet but my recommendations for you is to follow the posts on https://codepen.io/, 
you will find there a lot of useful examples, posts and tutorials.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. Do you have a specific pen codepen link as I've looked at this website for this animation?

Comment: yes, you can check the following links:
https://codepen.io/jcoulterdesign/pen/EPNrzg

https://codepen.io/JoostKiens/pen/LExggp

https://codepen.io/ettrics/pen/WRbGRN

and keep searching you will find more examples.